# Как работает getline()?

Tags: c++

Задача очень проста: на вход поступает количество принимаемых строк, и затем сами строки. На выход должно выйти (через пробел) количество гласных в этих строках.

```
// Подсчет гласных в строке
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <conio.h>   
using namespace std;

class count_predicate {
public:
    bool operator()(const char& expr) {
        if (
            expr == 'a' || expr == 'o' || expr == 'i'
            || expr == 'u' || expr == 'y' || expr == 'e'
           ) return true;

        return false;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int N; // Нужное количество строк
    cin >> N;
    string strs[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        getline(cin, strs[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int n = count_if(strs[i].begin(), strs[i].end(), count_predicate());
        cout << n << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Когда вместо `getline()` я использую обычный `cin>>`, то все работает, но строки попадаются с пробелами, поэтому гласные считаются некорректно. Здесь же почему-то `getline()` каким-то образом "перебивает" `cin` сверху, и считывает количество строк как еще одну строку, как я понял из теста программы (но это не точно). Собственно, почему так происходит?

И еще, у меня такое ощущение, что я решаю задачу очень топорно, есть ли какое-то более элегантное решение?
Особенно меня смущает количество проверок в предикате. Если такое решение есть, можно и без STL, ей я пользуюсь исключительно в учебных целях, закрепляю, так сказать, пройденный материал.

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, что у вас происходит с getline. Не могли бы вы продемонстрировать, что вы вводите, используя getline, что ожидаете получить, и что получаете в результате.

Comment: Используя getline, я считываю строки, чтобы затем подсчитать в них гласные. Сначала в cin я ввожу нужное количество строк, и за тем в первом цикле я ввожу сами эти строки. К примеру: 2(количество вводимых строк) aghqvi yioqiua *нажимаю Enter* и тут я должен ввести вторую строку, но на выходе получаю: 0 8

Comment: Я уже понял и написал вам ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Здесь же почему-то getline() каким-то образом "перебивает" cin сверху, и считывает количество строк как еще одну строку, как я понял из теста проги(но это не точно)

Нет, все проще. После считывания количества строк в буфере остается символ перевода строки. Вам просто надо сбросить буфер после считывания `N` - например, так:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(), '\n');
```

(это означает - считать и игнорировать все, пока не встретим '\n').

Еще - я бы переписал ваш оператор как

```
bool operator()(char expr) {
    return strchr("aoiuye",expr) != nullptr;
}
```

Остальное не смотрел...

Comment: Ваше решение помогло, спасибо. Но, если не трудно, не могли бы вы чуть подробнее описать, как работает cin.ignore ? К примеру, в параметр std::numeric_limits<> я ввел вместо <size_t>  <char> и у меня все равно все работает.

Comment: Работает, потому что вы не вводите, скажем, 300 символов после N :) Эта функция считывает не более первого параметра символов и выбрасывает их, но если по дороге ей попадается символ, указанный как второй параметр - она отбрасывает его и прекращает чтение. Т.е. русским языком - "считай и выбрось все до конца строки, но не более чем..." Там можно даже простое число поставить - типа `ignore(200,'\n')`, но я забил туда максимальное значение типа `size_t`. Просто как по мне - так корректнее, что ли... Гляньте тут - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 1):

После этого предложения

```
cin >> N;
```

в буфере потока ввода сохранился символ новой строки `'\n'. Поэтому первое обращение к буферу ввода с помощью функции`getline` приводит к тому, что считывается пустая строка.

Следует удалить этот символ новой строки из буфера перед использованием `getline` Делается это следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <limits>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#include <conio.h>   
using namespace std;

class count_predicate {
public:
    bool operator()(const char& expr) {
        if (
            expr == 'a' || expr == 'o' || expr == 'i'
            || expr == 'u' || expr == 'y' || expr == 'e'
           ) return true;

        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N; // Нужное количество строк
    cin >> N;
    string strs[N];

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   // ...
```

Предикат может быть записан проще

```
#include <cstring>

//...

struct count_predicate 
{
    bool operator()( const char &c ) const
    {
        const char *vowels = "aeiouy";
        return std::strchr( vowels, c );
    }
};
```